# Display any value in between -1 to 1 as 0 in RDLC report

Tags: c#, sql-server, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

This is a sample report Group by Customer. I'm calculating the balance value as:
`Fields!Bill.Value-SUM(Fields!Paid.Value)`

[image: Sample Report]

How to display balance Column as 0 if the value is in between -1 to 1

Comment: Did you already check out the `iif` statement? Something like this: `=iif(Fields!Bill.Value-SUM(Fields!Paid.Value) < -1 OR Fields!Bill.Value-SUM(Fields!Paid.Value) > 1, Fields!Bill.Value-SUM(Fields!Paid.Value), 0)`

Comment: Depends on how the iif is written: in my example I said "if sum is less than -1 or more than 1 then display the sum else display 0" - which is what you wrote: display all values between -1 and 1 as 0...

Comment: sorry mistaken, this works well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment as answer since this iif statement seems to solve your problem:

```
=iif(Fields!Bill.Value-SUM(Fields!Paid.Value) < -1 OR Fields!Bill.Value-SUM(Fields!Paid.Value) > 1, Fields!Bill.Value-SUM(Fields!Paid.Value), 0)
```